# Regex to select only numbers in this string and ignore words containing numbers

Tags: regex, string, char, numbers

I have this string:

> word3 203 0 189 word14 644252 63 0 0 0 0 0

I would like to write regex that will select only:

> 203 0 189 644252 63 0 0 0 0 0

and ignore

> word3 word14

I would really appreciate some help.
Thanks!

Comment: `\b\d+\b` -  match word boundaries.

Comment: Thank you Alex K. - its working! Thanks alot.